# WPF Triggers WebBrowser Navigating/Navigated

Tags: wpf, xaml, browser

**My Question :**
How can i trigger webbrowser events like navigating/navigated so that i can animate the whole browser ?

*I can't find those 2 actions in Triggers panel in Blend 4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventTriggers` only work with `RoutedEvents`, those events are not routed.

You can handle those events and animate in code.

---

Apart from that you can use Blend's Interactivity:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

```
<WebBrowser>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction>
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                        <!-- Storyboard here -->
                    </ei:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                </ei:ControlStoryboardAction>
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</WebBrowser>
```

I am surprised that their use is not integrated into Blend's trigger editing UI.